# How do optimize nested loop and filter from another list using linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to filter a flattened nested loop and filter from another list.  So below is what I have been able to do. I tried this approach but when I run the query it does not save anything in the database.  I  need help to check and ignore existing records (same MemberId and Description) in the Tasklist table.

```
var addedtop = from a in db.TaskLists select new {a.MemberId,a.Description};
var membtasks = from m in members
                        from n in tasks
                        select new { m, n };

       
        TaskList taskList = new TaskList();
        foreach (var item in membtasks)
        {
            var exist = db.TaskLists.Where(a => a.Description == item.n && a.MemberId == item.m);
            if(exist == null)
            {    
            taskList .Description = item.n;
            taskList .MemberId = item.m;
            db.taskList .Add(taskList );
            db.SaveChanges();

            }
       }
        return Redirect(url);
```

Comment: *it does not save anything* - have you used a debugger to step your code and look at how it works? `Where` will never return null, which leads me to think you haven't even tried to debug this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `exists` will never be `null`. The line `var exist = db.TaskLists.Where(a => a.Description == item.n && a.MemberId == item.m);` returns an `IQueryable` that describes your query but hasn't actually executed against the database yet.

Try changing the line to:

```
var exist = db.TaskLists.Where(a => a.Description == item.n && a.MemberId == item.m).SingleOrDefault();
```

This executes the query and checks if there is a single item that satisfies your query. If there is no result at all the query returns `null` which will execute the code inside your if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement has not been executed query, you can change Where to Any like this:

```
var exist = db.TaskLists.Any(a => a.Description == item.n && a.MemberId == item.m);
```

`Any` function that returns data type is `bool`